# ScrollView doesn't keep track of current position. When tapped it resets back to previous location

Tags: reactjs, react-native, scroll, scrollview

Steps of the problem:
1: Scroll down page from location x
2: *Page Scrolls to location y*
3: Release finger 
4: User taps finger again to continue scrolling
5: Location on the ScrollView resets back to location x causing a jump back and prevents further scrolling

I've tried to look up information regarding react-native-modal and ScrollView to find the issue & can't find any occurrences of this

Library-in-use: react-native-modal

```
scrollOffset: 0  
scrollViewRef

handleScrollTo = p => {
  if (this.scrollViewRef) {
    this.scrollViewRef.scrollTo(p);
  }
};

    <Modal
      isVisible={this.state.visibleModal}
      onSwipeComplete={() => this.setState({ visibleModal: false })}
      swipeDirection="down"
      scrollTo={this.handleScrollTo}
      scrollOffset={this.state.scrollOffset}
      scrollOffsetMax={400 - 300} // content height - ScrollView height
      style={screenStyles.bottomModal}
      useNativeDriver
    >
      {this._renderModalContent()}
    </Modal>


      // Render modal content (there's a view wrapping this)
      <ScrollView 
        style ={{flex: 8, paddingLeft: '10%', paddingTop: '10%'}}
        ref={ref => (this.scrollViewRef = ref)}
        onScroll={event => {this.state.scrollOffset = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y}}
        scrollEventThrottle={16}>
      >
        {Object.keys(balances).map(
            symbol =>
              symbolPriceTicker[`${symbol}USDT`] &&
              COIN_INFO[symbol] &&  (
                <TouchableOpacity
                  key={`c-${symbol}`}
                  style={screenStyles.assetSelector.selector}
                  onPress={() => this.selectAsset(symbol)}
                >
                  <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                    <Image
                      style={screenStyles.assetSelector.coinAvatar}
                      source={COIN_INFO[symbol] ? COIN_INFO[symbol].avatar_32 : null}
                    />
                    <Text style={screenStyles.assetSelector.coinName}>
                      {COIN_INFO[symbol].name}
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              ),
          )}
      </ScrollView>
```

Comment: it may be the issue with the style of the warpping view , do you use "flex-start" there?

Comment: onSwipeComplete={() => this.setState({ visibleModal: false })}
      scrollTo={this.handleScrollTo}
      scrollOffset={this.state.scrollOffset}
      scrollOffsetMax={400 - 300} //  try commenting these in the model, may be logic of the visibleModal state has the role in this problem

Comment: @Adarsh Hmmm.  For justifyContent & alignItems? What should I flex-start

Comment: no need , just to clarify

Comment: @Adarsh Just commented them out, scrolling no longer works

Comment: try commant onSwipeComplete only, sorry i can't figure it out from the  above codes

Comment: @Adarsh did a console.log and when I scroll the offset increases then after i release it decreases. . . it always goes back to offset: 100

Comment: That's may be you use scrollOffsetsetMax={100}

Comment: @Adarsh Yup that fixed that issue, however since the entire page is a bunch of TouchableOpacities.  How would you ensure scrolling so that onPress doesn't take touches while scrolling (that also resets the position of the scrollOffset)

Comment: Did the links in my answer helps?. I think ScrollView handles it, while we scroll it doesn't take the clicks

Comment: @Adarsh Yes it did, thanks! However, ScrollView isn't handling the touches as the offset automatically resets when onPress gets called :/.  Any idea?

Comment: Will check it out, please try to share a sample content inside the ScrollView, will reply in a while, early morning here

Comment: @Adarsh Done! Appreciate your help my friend

Comment: please check disableScrollViewPanResponder props in Scrollview, u can manage it with state, if u feels problem with child components touch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its may be the problem with props in the Model which is related to scroll.

as you use `ScrollView` inside the `Model`, assuming that , you need a dismissable scrollview

Please checkout a sample related to that : https://gist.github.com/mmitchellgarcia/6ee4d5b5c79162e3cc13b67d743777e6#file-dismissablescrollview-js

For more : https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-modal/issues/109

Hope it helps